# Exclamation mark in table.column !=0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008 I have a query which resembles this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable mt
WHERE mt.ID !=0
```

What is the `!=0` ?  It looks like it's the same as saying `<> 0`.

I am unable to google this, is this in fact the same?  A link to some documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: It is the same: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx

Comment: You are right. That's the non-standard way of writing `<>`

Comment: >>"I am unable to google this". Try `sqlserver unequal` and you are able to Google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly the same operator as `<>`.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `C` convention for "not equal". There is another `C` convention for "equal" that looks like `==`.

Comment: Does `==` work in SQL or tsql?